# SublimeREPL Giving Syntax Errors

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I have tried to follow the instructions on SUBLIMEREPL. Due to me trying to use the input() function, I was told to use SublimeREPL. My code is simple.

`val = input(" Please tell my name sir/ma'am")`

After installing the SublimeREPL through the Package Control "Insert Package".
I went to Tools> Sublime REPL> Python and put in

```
 Python-RUN Current file
```

Here is the error I am getting.
[SublimeREPL Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvnTw.png)

Comment: Are you literally typing `Python - RUN Current File` into the REPL? Don't do that. Save the file you want to run, then select **`Tools → SublimeREPL → Python → Python - RUN Current File`** *from the menu*. You don't have to type anything in.

Comment: OMG. I'm so dumb. Yes, it works fine now.